# Can i create custom server log for jboss with server cpu utilization and disk usages?

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j, jboss-logging

I am trying to create customized jboss server log with server cpu utilization and disk usages. Please let me know if any one has any idea about the same.

I am thinking of writting a class and calling that  class  in jboss-log4j.xml.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the disk usages, if you want to log jvm metrics like cpu utilization, heap usage, thread counts etc you could have a look at [jmxtrans](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans/wiki). It queries the configured jmx metrics and provides various output writers including a Log4jWriter.

Comment: Thanks Andy, jmxtrans is working fine but I think doing it through shell script would be better.

Comment: How would get process specific resource usage like jvm's cpu usage through a shell script? If there is only one jvm running on that machine then the system's cpu usage could be assumed to be the jvm's cpu usage

Comment: I have created script file where i am finding ps for jboss and echoing to log file. its working file .